# Change design of regular and sale price separately if there is a sale price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor, price

I'm using Elementor Pro to create a webshop. I created a single product page design with the Product Price widget and styled it to my needs. But I want to separate the design of the regular and sale price (if there's a sale price), like this (without Info icon). When there's no sale price I want the regular price to be shown in the red background.

[image]

How can I do this? I searched the internet but couldn't find any solution.

Thanks!